# Which graph is better?

Tags: trigonometry

I have to draw the function 
f(x)=3|sinx|-sinx

Which way is better?

First pic
[image: option1]
Second pic
[image: option2]

Comment: I think, the first one.

Comment: You neglected the fact that if $\sin x<0$ then $-4\sin x>0. \qquad$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first one is right.

The second one is very close but you (I'm assuming you drew that) are forgetting the fact that if $\sin x < 0$, then $-4\sin x > 0$.